# Produce outcome values based on random number generate

Tags: python, rank, random-seed

I have a random number generator and am trying to produce outcomes based on this number. I have three outcomes in three columns. 'Away Win', 'Draw', 'Home Win' and have the probabilities of these events. Based on the random number function, I want to simulate a column of expected results.

```
       Prob_Away_Win  Prob_Draw  Prob_Home_Win  Random_Value  Expected_Res
    0  0.14588        0.37896    0.58646        0.12457       1
    1  0.11167        0.31267    0.57566        0.78643       3
    2  0.23312        0.41235    0.35453        0.27642       2
    3  0.44532        0.32112    0.23358        0.18754       3
    4  0.83216        0.12980    0.03804        0.43823       1
    5  0.21334        0.09897    0.68769        0.16721       1
```

So, for example. Looking at the first row, With a random value of 0.12457, I want to first ask is this value less than than the smallest probability available in any of the three 'Prob' columns. Yes, it's smaller than 'Prob_Away_Win' so I want value '1' to reflect column 1. Looking at the next row, is the probability smaller than the smallest value? No. So.. Is it smaller than the smallest value (0.11167) + the next smallest value (0.31267)? No. Therefore I want Expected_Res to choose '3' as it was the last column remaining.  For the next row in the Dataframe, again I wish to ask is the Random Value less than smallest value available. No. It is less than the smallest possible value, 'Prob_Away_Win (0.23312) + the next smallest value 'Prob_Home_Win' (0.35453) = 0.58765. Yes. So choose column '2' Pro_Home_Win.

How could I create a function that would calculate this?

Comment: what have you tried so far, what libraries are you using?  there are **many** options here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation with `itertools.accumulate` and `itertools.takewhile`:

```
data = '''       Prob_Away_Win  Prob_Draw  Prob_Home_Win  Random_Value  Expected_Res
    0  0.14588        0.37896    0.58646        0.12457       1
    1  0.11167        0.31267    0.57566        0.78643       3
    2  0.23312        0.41235    0.35453        0.27642       2
    3  0.44532        0.32112    0.23358        0.18754       3
    4  0.83216        0.12980    0.03804        0.43823       1
    5  0.21334        0.09897    0.68769        0.16721       1'''

import re
from itertools import accumulate, takewhile

tbl = []
for g in re.findall(r'\s*([\d.]+)\s*([\d.]+)\s*([\d.]+)\s*([\d.]+)\s*([\d.]+)\s*([\d.]+)', data):
    l = [*map(float, g)]
    tbl.append(l)

for row in tbl:
    probs = sorted(enumerate(row[1:4], 1), key=lambda k: k[1])
    random_value = row[4]
    t = takewhile(lambda p: random_value>p[1], accumulate(probs, lambda a, b: (b[0], a[1] + b[1])))
    idx = probs[sum(1 for _ in t)][0]
    print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(int(row[0]),
        ' '.join('{: <{}}'.format('(*)' + s if i==idx else s, 12) for i, s in enumerate(map(str, row[1:5]), 1)  ),
        idx))
```

Prints:

```
0   (*)0.14588   0.37896      0.58646      0.12457      1
1   0.11167      0.31267      (*)0.57566   0.78643      3
2   0.23312      0.41235      (*)0.35453   0.27642      3
3   0.44532      0.32112      (*)0.23358   0.18754      3
4   (*)0.83216   0.1298       0.03804      0.43823      1
5   (*)0.21334   0.09897      0.68769      0.16721      1
```